# Changing shell inside a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

in the default shell
the for loop given below

```
for ((i=$llimit; i<=$ulimit; i++)); 
do 
  echo $i
done;
```

it throws error "'((' is not expected"

but when switching to the bash shell

the for loop works fine

is there a way to change shell inside a shellscript

or any other solution as this for loop is inside a shell script

EDIT:

this is hte shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
nav_var=`sqlplus -s tcs384160/tcs#1234 <<\EOF
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
select max(sequence#) from v$archived_log where applied='YES' and thread#=2 and        dest_id=2;
exit;
EOF`
echo $nav_var;
ulimit=`expr $nav_var - 30`;
llimit=`expr $ulimit - 200`;
for ((i=$llimit; i<=$ulimit; i++));
do ls -l arch_aceprod_2_${i}_743034701.arc;
done;
```

Comment: Typically, it is the so-called shebang line (e.g., `#!/usr/bin/env bash` as the very first line) that controls what shell executes the script. What is it in your case? Can you just change it to bash?

Comment: from the home directory typing bash makes it change shell to bash the default shell i think is ksh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C-style `for` loop you've used is a *bashism*.

Change the line

```
for ((i=$llimit; i<=$ulimit; i++));
```

to

```
for i in $(seq $llimit $ulimit);
```

and it would work well with both `sh` and `bash`.

---

EDIT: If you don't have `seq`, you could change the loop as:

```
i=$llimit
while [ $i -le $ulimit ]; do
  echo "Do something here"
  let i=i+1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

By "default shell" I assume you mean /bin/sh?  Is there a line starting "#!" at the top of the script?

Bash is pretty much backwards compatible with sh.  If you put "#!/bin/bash" (without the quotes) as the first line this should get the whole thing to run under bash.

Answer (score -2):

try another for loop syntax

```
for counter in {$llimit..$ulimit}
do

your logic

done
```

this works for all type of shells.

Or #!bin/bash will also work in your case

Comment: Did you know that brace expansion happens before variable expansion, and that this __won't__ work?

Comment: arch_aceprod_2_{170801..171001}_*.arc not found

Comment: The only shell I am aware of that supports this is `zsh`.